# Controll ASC / DESC sorting by CASE condition

Tags: sql

```
with t(col) as(
    values
    (0),
    (1)
)
select * from t 
ORDER BY  
CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN col END ASC,
CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN col END DESC
```

Well, is this   correct syntax for controlling `ASC / DESC` ordering by `CASE` expression?

Yes, this works and gives correct result's, though seems somehow not intuitive (for me at least), because `ASC` and `DESC` are outside of `CASE..END` block.

Probably sounds silly question, but, in this example, first condition is false, so what happens to `ASC` keyword? asking this because it is after the `END` of block, so little bit confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax in general for controlling `asc`/`desc`.  For specifically numerical values, you can use the negation trick:

```
order by (case when @desc = 1 then - col else col end),
```

In your example, the first `case` expression returns `NULL`.  These are all equivalent for the purpose of ordering, so no order is imposed.

Why is the `asc`/`desc` outside the `case`?  Because `case` is an *expression* in SQL that returns a scalar value.  A scalar value is a single value, such as a date, string, or number (some databases expand this to include records, arrays, and/or tuples).  The `asc`/`desc` is a syntactic element in the `order by` clause; it is not part of a scalar value.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  "In your example, the first case expression returns NULL", yes, most likely that is correct, though also interesting is that direct using `ORDER BY  NULL ASC ` yields error. at least in postgres

Comment: @OtoShavadze . . . Many databases discourage ordering by a constant.